# MySQL Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out this error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`freight`.`rates_detail`, CONSTRAINT `rates_detail_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`component_id`) REFERENCES `computation` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Here's what I'm trying to do(from the log):

```
INSERT INTO freight.rates_detail(rate_id,component_id,uom,rate,inc_or) values(0821,01,00,011.00,'Y')
```

I repeatedly looked and looked and reviewed the values of `id` in table `computation` and the value in that case: 01 exists.

What's the problem with this?

Comment: What is the data type of your `component_id` column?

Comment: Check if  component_id column is the same type adn length as the id column in computation.

Comment: @eggyal: they're all `int` with length: 11

Comment: @Mihai: It *must* be the same type for the foreign key constraint to exist.

Comment: Just a side note (not related to your problem): an `int` does not have "*a length*". The 11 is only a hint for a client application to be used when displaying the data. It does **not** limit the possible values in any way. You can store the same values in an `int(1)` and an `int(11)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But can you create the foreign key if the lengths (which are not length P) are different?

Comment: @eggshot: Do you get any useful information from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` immediately after receiving this error?

Comment: @eggyal: i just found out that the reference table is `MyISAM` not `InnoDB` will it affect?

Comment: @eggshot: Yes, that will be the problem.  MySQL requires both tables to use the same storage engine (and not MyISAM) in order for foreign key constraints to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i just found out that the reference table is `MyISAM` not `InnoDB` will it affect?

Yes.  As documented under [Using `FOREIGN KEY` Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> The parent and child tables must use the same storage engine.

It goes on to say:

> For storage engines that do not support foreign keys (such as [`MyISAM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)), MySQL Server parses and ignores foreign key specifications.